# Puedo usar la clase scanner para leer ficheros binarios

Tags: java

No se si la puedo usar o no, ¿puedo usar la clase Scanner para leer ficheros binarios?

Comment: Nada es imposible, según veo, se puede.

Comment: @NaCl virtualmente se podría, pero usar un `Scanner` para procesar un archivo binario es como limpiar el agua de mar quitando las sales, granos de arena y demás impurezas usando pinzas y herramientas similares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La clase `Scanner` no se puede utilizar para ficheros binarios.

Para ello puedes utilizar por ejemplo [`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html).

Answer (score -1):

Algunas alternativas:

---

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;

Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file");
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

---

```
byte[] array = Files.readAllBytes(new File("/path/to/file").toPath());
```

---

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class ReadFileInByteArrayWithFileInputStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("inputfile.txt");

        FileInputStream fin = null;

        try {

            fin = new FileInputStream(file);

            byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];


            fin.read(fileContent);

            String s = new String(fileContent);
            System.out.println("File content: " + s);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found" + e);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Exception while reading file " + ioe);
        }
        finally {

            try {
                if (fin != null) {
                    fin.close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("Error while closing stream: " + ioe);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html

---